# how to determine whether (Q, ◦) is a group without knowing the operator?

Tags: linear-algebra

I'm taking the course "Algebra 2" this semester, and I got the following problem:

8. Let G = (Z, ◦) be a group such that the operation ◦ is defined over Q. Then:

A. ( $\mathbb{N}$, ◦) is a group.

B. ($\mathbb{Q}$, ◦) is a group.

C. both ($\mathbb{N}$, ◦) and ($\mathbb{Q}$, ◦) are groups.

D. neither ($\mathbb{N}$, ◦) nor ($\mathbb{Q}$, ◦) are groups.

E. None of the above.

I ruled out option A and option C because if the operator ◦ is defined over Z and Q, it might be something that yields a negative number, which does not belong to N, thus making (N,◦) not an algebraic structure.
Its not D because (Q, ◦) can be a group if the operator is +, for example.

So its either B or E, and I cant seem to convince myself its one or the other.
Can someone point me in the right direction?
I'm fairly new to this stuff so if you could keep it simple, it would be most appreciated.
Thank you!

Comment: The wording of the question is a little ambiguous. Would it be correct to interpret A-E as: A. $(N, \circ)$ *must* be a group, etc.?

Comment: I would add that the wording is a lot ambiguous. What are $Z,N,Q$? They *look like* the integers, natural numbers, and rational numbers, but if they are then that should be said explicitly. But what's worse, what does it mean for $\circ$ to be "defined over $Q$"?

Comment: B is false. Just define ◦ on $\mathbb{Q}$ by  $x ◦ y = x+y$ if $x, y \in \mathbb{Z}$ and $x ◦ y = 0$ if $x, y \in \mathbb{Q} \setminus \mathbb{Z}$. It is immediate that $(\mathbb{Z} ,◦)$ is a group, but $(\mathbb{Q} ,◦)$  is not a group.

Comment: Another thing: please typeset your mathematical notation using [mathjax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: I'd have written "D. neither (N, ◦) nor (Q, ◦) is a group." rather than treating that is plural.

Comment: Welcome Guy. To see that B false (that means that $(\mathbb{Q} ,◦)$  may not be a group), just define ◦ on $\mathbb{Q}$ by  $x ◦ y = x+y$ if $x, y \in \mathbb{Z}$ and $x ◦ y = 0$ if $x, y \in \mathbb{Q} \setminus \mathbb{Z}$. It is immediate that $(\mathbb{Z} ,◦)$ is a group, but $(\mathbb{Q} ,◦)$  is not a group.

Comment: thank you for the comments.
@Ramiro, if i define x◦y=x+y  if x,y $\in \mathbb{Z}$, doesn't that mean x◦y=x+y if x,y $\in \mathbb{Q}$? shouldn't the operator mean the same for both?

Comment: correction: meant to say x◦y=0 if x,y $\in \mathbb{Q}$.
and another thing, why does that fact that  x◦y=0 if x,y $\in \mathbb{Q}$ means that ($\mathbb{Q}$, ◦) is not a group?

Comment: An operator ◦ defined on $\mathbb{Q}$ is any function from $\mathbb{Q}\times\mathbb{Q}$ to $\mathbb{Q}$. You can define such function as you wish.